# How to redirect symbold url generated by search form to original url using .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

When a user types his code in the form , it should open his page.

For eg : when user types CODE: ABCD , then it should open page domainname.com/ABCD, but its giving domainname.com/?code=ABCD.

I used .htaccess

```
redirect 301 /?code=ABCD /ABCD.
```

But not working.

Any suggestions to redirect these url with question marks and equals to to plain URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not access querystrings like that. You need to match against %{QUERY_STRING} using mod-rewrite

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^code=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^$ /%1? [L,R]
```

This will redirect :

- domain.com/?code=helloworld

to

- domain.com/helloworld